# Vector operations with different representations

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Let's take the following two vectors as an example

```
v1 = [2, 4, 6]
v2 = [3, 5, 7]
```

When vectors are represented in this form, does this mean that they are both a 3D vector, that is, every element in the vector represents a value in one dimension?

If so, correct me if I am wrong but the only way how we can work out vector operations in this form is in the following manner

```
v1+v2 = [5, 9, 13]
v1*2 (scalar multiply) = [4, 8, 12]
```

This means that when it comes to adding these two vectors we are actually adding each dimension with each other correct?

To calculate the distance, we can then use Pythagoras which means that we would be calculating the Euclidean distance of the vectors right?

Also, what exactly is vector clamping?

I am just looking for some clarification.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Everything that you've written is correct.  Each of the three numbers that make up the vectors are called *components* of the vectors.  You can say that addition of vectors is *componentwise.*